# radio button - group all except one group

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I did already get some help on here before, but now I'm experiencing an new problem:

Several radio-buttons have a dynamically given name, which I can't change.

So I first wanted to "group" all radio-buttons inside a listing. You can see it working in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DwL7J/1/

This is the code which is used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        // When any radio button on the page is selected,
        // then deselect all other radio buttons.
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Now I want, that the first two "groups" stay grouped, but the last group called "Schutzfolie" should be handled as a separate group. So I can only choose one of the "Format"-radio-buttons, but along this I can choose one of the "Schutzfolie"-radio-buttons. It would be nice to preselect the first one of the "Schutzfolie"-radio-buttons called "ohne", unless someone hits another radio-button of this last group...

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I get it, is this what you're looking for -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DwL7J/2/)

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to achieve, thx a very lot! I tried something very similar, but there must have been an error in my try...thank you again! Great! I love this forum!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exclude the last group:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').not('[name="id[3]"]').change(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').not(this).not('[name="id[3]"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
});​
```